# installing app in development on retail phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can I use a retail phone to test apps I'm developing for wp7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use a retail phone to test Windows Phone 7 apps **but** you'll need to register as a developer on the [Windows Phone Marketplace](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/home/about/how_it_works) ($99 USD/year) to be able to register your phone as a developer device.

Once your phone is registered as a developer device, follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769512%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: I guess MS will get their $100/year after all. My app is so piddly, I couldn't decide if it was worth $100 to submit. Android made the decision easy for me, just a one-time $25 fee to submit to their market place. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft is missing the point, considering that the Windows Phone Market place is being charged and unavailable for developers living in different parts of the world. How do they expect their phones to to pick in such places, if local apps cannot be programmed into it?

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment, if at all, as it is not an answer to the question.